# Migrating TDE Protected Database - Cert Migrated, Manual Copy Works, But Not Copy Wizard

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm attempting to migrate several DB from an SQL 2014 to 2016 server. They all have TDE enabled, and are protected by a certificate.

I successfully copied the certificate, and I am able to manually export and import the database without issues. However when attempting to use the "Tasks > Copy Database" Wizard from the SQL Management Studio, I receive the error

"InnerException-->Cannot change database encryption state because no database encryption key is set."

Everything I can find on this says the error is a result of the encryption key/cert not being copied across properly, however I assume the fact I am able to manually export/import the DB means the cert is copied and working?

I believe the copy wizard will copy DB & server accounts without orphaning anything or requiring password changes, and the manual import/export will result in orphaned accounts and require password changes. As well as just the fact that using the Copy Wizard will be routinely simpler.

What am I missing?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but have you considered using the [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) PowerShell module to do the migration?